# Поменять картинку в разделе "Как удалить свою учетную запись?"

Tags: обсуждение, предлагаемые-правки, правки

В доке "[Как удалить свою учетную запись?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account)" картинка с en подсайта. Может заменить на картинку с ru SO?

Comment: Да там еще и доисторический дизайн на картинке...

Comment: Эту страницу справки надо переписать. Хотя бы потому что я вижу у себя кнопку "удалить профиль", но совсем в другом месте.

Comment: Я так понимаю, после редизайна не поменяли раздел.

Comment: [Ждите](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40979258#40979258) скоро на Мете.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Большое спасибо за предложение! Добавил страницу справки в виде [общего вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6328/6), доступного всем для редактирования! Пожалуйста, вносите улучшения!