# Улучшение страницы «Как удалить свою учетную запись?»

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Заголовок: How do I delete my account?
Ссылка на текущую версию на английском языке: https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account

---

*User deletion is irreversible! By sending this request, your votes will be revoked, and all of your content will be made anonymous.*

You should see a [Delete Profile](/users/delete/current) option on your user profile by clicking the *Edit Profile & Settings* link at the top of your profile page:

[image: self-delete from profile]

Visit that page and read through the information there. Once you've done so,
 check the box to indicate that you understand the implications of deleting your profile and then click the Delete Profile button.

If you have never posted or voted more than once on your profile, it will be *immediately* deleted. Otherwise, you will be scheduled for deletion. During that time, you can cancel the deletion request by visiting your profile and clicking the cancel link in the banner at the top. Otherwise, it will be deleted after 24 hours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Заголовок: Как удалить свою учетную запись?
Ссылка на текущую версию на русском языке: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account

---

*Удаление пользователя необратимо! При отправке данного запроса ваши голоса будут отозваны, а все ваши сообщения станут анонимными.*

Вы можете найти [ссылку для удаления аккаунта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/delete/current) нажав *Править* вверху страницы вашего профиля.

[image: Картинка]

---

Прочитайте внимательно информацию на этой странице. Как закончите, установите флажок, тем самым показав, что вы понимаете последствия удаления своего профиля, а затем нажмите кнопку «Удалить профиль».

Если вы никогда не отправляли сообщений или голосовали не более одного раза на этом аккаунте, он будет *немедленно* удален. В противном случае ваш запрос будет поставлен в очередь на удаление. За это время вы можете отменить запрос, посетив свой профиль и нажав ссылку отмены на баннере сверху страницы. Или же он будет удален через 24 часа.

Comment: "Если вы никогда не отправляли сообщений или голосовали не более одного раза на этом аккаунте". А тут действительно условие "или" работает? То есть если написал кучу сообщений, но не голосовал, то аккаунт удаляется сразу?

Comment: @eugeneek вероятно, там "и" должно быть, всё же.